# Region method on Venn Diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are $34$ students in a group that there are the people who speak german and french and $14$ people who speak minimum a language **(French or German)**. $23$ people who speak maximum a language.

- How many students who speak minimum a language are there?

So, how do we solve this question with region method?

Let's give numbers for the regions while applying it on the Venn Diagram.

I mean like

$$\sum_{i=i} r(i) = 34$$

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) = 34$$

$$r(1) + r(2) = 14$$

Hope you got what i mean.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming references of regions as: $r(1)$ to only French speaking students, $r(2)$ to only German speaking students, $r(3)$ to both language speakers and $r(4)$ to neither language speakers.

---

$$\sum_{i=1} r(i) = 34$$

$$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) = 34$$

$$r(1) + r(2) +r(3)= 14$$ (since minimum one language means **at least one** language)

$$r(4) + r(1) +r(2)= 23$$ (since maximum one language means **at most one** language)

---

From the above equations, we get-

$r(3) = 11$ (students that speak **both** languages)

$r(4)=20$ (students that speak **neither** language)

$r(1)+r(2)=3$ (students that speak **only one** language).

---

I am not sure what the question is asking but this is all that can be ascertained by what is given in the question (given that I understood it correctly).

---

**Calculations-**

$$r(1) + r(2) +r(3)= 14$$

Adding $r(4)$ to both sides,

$$r(1) + r(2) +r(3)+r(4)= 14+r(4)$$

$$34=14+r(4)$$

$$r(4)=20$$

---

$$r(4) + r(1) +r(2)= 23$$

Adding $r(3)$ to both sides,

$$r(1) + r(2) +r(3)+r(4)= 23+r(3)$$

$$34=23+r(3)$$

$$r(3)=11$$

---

Replacing $r(3)$ and $r(4)$ in first equation by their values,

$$r(1) + r(2) + 11 + 20 = 34$$

$$r(1) + r(2) = 3$$

Comment: Also, don't call it region method. It's just a way of getting it done without lots of notations and to avoid confusion. :P

Comment: What is this method called by? Also, why didn't you do it like your last answer?

Comment: @Korrigi It's not a recognised method. It's just a way to get the question solved. You probably won't find it anywhere. This just simplifies calculations into parts. Formally, in set theory, the union-intersection notation is used. You can use this 'method' to check your answer or maybe to answer mcqs without much hassle, but formally it is not accepted, maybe you can use it to justify your answer but it's generally neither recognised nor accepted. I just use it because it is easy to understand.

Comment: @Korrigi I just didn't make the Venn Diagram here, as the regions are few here.

Comment: However, you didn't do it like your last answer. I didn't mean that.

Comment: You were adding something to the both side. This seems like the best way to solve this. Are you sure that I can't find anywhere?

Comment: @Korrigi I just omitted and didn't write the calculation part. You can add to both sides to make it equal to the first equation, or you could subtract from equations. These methods are called Elimination Method and Substitution Method, to solve linear equations. You can use any. No problem there.

Comment: Can you show the calcuation part? I really need it and love this method.

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure you won't find it anywhere.

Comment: By the way, If you can show the calcuation part, I'd be too happy. I'm wondering how we do it like your last answer.

Comment: @Korrigi Alright. I'll update my answer, including calculations, in a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you are great. I'm waiting then and want to take your suggestions after it.

Comment: I've exam tomorrow. So, I want to solve these questions with the easiest way. Waiting your update ;)

Comment: @Korrigi updated. Also, maybe this method won't be accepted unless it's an mcq as examiners aren't aware of this. You might have to write a note in the beginning, what the notations mean.

Comment: @Korrigi Also, replace $r$ by $n$ for the exam which is more widely used to denote number of elements in a set.

Comment: Oh, I will. ;)) Also this method is the greatest method I've seen. Let's assume that we weren't given the sum. What will we do?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1} r(i) = 34$ assume that this wasn't given. What should we do?

Comment: @Korrigi then you won't be able to find anything of importance here. With that gone, the 2 remaining equations won't provide us with a lot.

Comment: What do you mean? If it asks how many students totally are there, won't we be able to find it?

Comment: @Korrigi specifically to this question atleast, you won't be able to get to a concrete answer if you didn't have that equation with you. You might be able to cross off the values that the regions **can't** take but there's no solid answer for any of the regions.

Comment: didn't get anything :/ Must it be given?

Comment: @Korrigo that's okay. I'm pretty sure your questions will provide you with sufficient information to ascertain anything. Also, read and practice the Substitution method and Elimination method for linear equations. That will help.

Comment: Let"s assume that we need to find the total people, can we use this method for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68193/discussion-between-maadhav-gupta-and-korrigi).